# How do app monitoring apps/sites know apps have changed price?

Tags: ios, database, rss, app-store

There doesn't seem to be an Apple RSS feed which shows apps that were paid and have become free, so how do app monitoring sites know that a site has changed price? Are they somehow constantly recording the prices of RSS apps in a database (cron job? or via an app?) and then noticing the price changes? or is there some other way?

Comment: I'd guess regular polling, as you suggested.

Comment: ok but how technically would you even go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Apple have a [public API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html) for loading info on products in the App Store.